# Problem fetching the all the first table records when joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tables are Service, Plan, Subscribe. The requirement is to get all the records in Service table, but the records should be ordered based on the most subscription counts. I am able to fetch the records based on the joining condition, but unable to fetch the records in Service table which doesn't have the subscription.

Please note. Every Service record has a Plan. But there can be Service, which don't have a Subscription.

```
**Service**
service_id
service_name
status
is_active

**Plan**
plan_id
service_id
plan_name
plan_cost

**Subscribe**
subscribe_id
plan_id
person_name

SELECT DISTINCT s.service_id FROM service s JOIN plan p on s.service_id=p.service_id join
subscribe su on p.plan_id=su.plan_id WHERE
(s.status='Published' AND s.is_active=1) GROUP BY su.plan_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(su.subscribe_id) DESC
```

Could someone please look into this problem and help.

Comment: Search for left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be a three way join between the tables, aggregating by *subscription*, not by plan.  Something like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM service s
LEFT JOIN plan p
    ON s.service_id = p.service_id
LEFT JOIN subscribe su
    ON p.plan_id = su.plan_id
GROUP BY
    s.service_id
ORDER BY
    COUNT(su.subscribe_id) DESC;
```

If you also want to select the subscription count, then you may add the `COUNT(su.subscribe_id)` term to the select clause.  Note that aggregating by `service_id` alone, while selecting all columns from the `service` table, should be valid here assuming that `service_id` is a primary key in that table.

Comment: Yes. It worked. I worked with my colleague and found the same solution, only difference is we have grouped it as "service_id" and the "su.plan_id". Getting the same results. By looking at your example, it simplifies more. Thx lot.

Answer (score 0):

well, the simplest answer is that you want a left join so that you can get all records in service + any records in subscribe that match.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.service_id 
FROM service s 
JOIN plan p on s.service_id=p.service_id 
left join subscribe su on p.plan_id=su.plan_id 
WHERE
(s.status='Published' AND s.is_active=1) 
GROUP BY su.plan_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(isnull(su.subscribe_id,0)) DESC
```

also, you probably want to move the count into the select section. like this:

```
select * from 
SELECT  s.service_id, COUNT(isnull(su.subscribe_id,0)) as [cnt]
FROM service s 
JOIN plan p on s.service_id=p.service_id 
left join subscribe su on p.plan_id=su.plan_id 
WHERE
(s.status='Published' AND s.is_active=1) 
GROUP BY su.plan_id ) A
ORDER BY  [cnt] DESC
```

I used a SQL server convention for column aliases. If you're using a different DBMS just change it accordingly. If you have cases where service doesn't have a plan you should change that to a left join as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still I'm facing the same issue. I tried your suggestion. But still I am getting the records for the matching conditions, but not the all Service records. There are records which having the matching with first join, but not the second join. Those records didn't fetched. Please help

Comment: did you try changing "join plan" to "left join plan" ?

Comment: Yes. Same result.

Comment: what does this return?     SELECT  s.service_id,*
FROM service s 
JOIN plan p on s.service_id=p.service_id 
left join subscribe su on p.plan_id=su.plan_id 
WHERE
(s.status='Published' AND s.is_active=1)